# Calculate the‍‌‍ ‍ ‍‌‍‌‍ minimum number of bricks

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

- `arr1 =>` denotes a tower.
- The numbers in the array denotes the number of bricks used to build the tower.
- We want the tower to be either ascending or descending, with the height difference between two consecutive elements being 1.

Calculate the `minimum number of bricks` needed.

```
Example:
arr1 = [1, 3, 5, 8] 
arr1(ascending): [5, 6, 7 , 8] 
Bricks needed: 4 + 3 + 2 = 9
```

```
Example:
arr1 = [3, 10, 9, 9, 4]
arr2(descending): [12, 11, 10, 9, 8]
Bricks needed:  9+1+1+4 = 15
```

Code:

```
arr = [1, 3, 5, 8] 

n=len(arr)

lmax=max(arr[i]+i for i in range(n))
res=sum(lmax-i-arr[i] for i in range(n))

print(res)
```

The output is `21` but it should be `9.`

Comment: Why do you think that should work?

Comment: It feels like you haven't given us all of the requirements/assumptions.  For example, if I want a tower of height four, surely I could just stack four bricks one on top of the other, for a minimum of four bricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you use is a just a bit off. `i` should be subtracted (and added again in the second expression). So it should be:

```
lmax = max(arr[i] - i for i in range(n))
res = sum(lmax + i - arr[i] for i in range(n))
```

And then you need to compare which of the two possibilities (ascending, descending) needs the lesser bricks:

```
def solve(lst):
    def bricks_ascending(lst):
        lmax = max(height - i for i, height in enumerate(lst))
        return sum(lmax + i - height for i, height in enumerate(lst))

    return min(bricks_ascending(lst), bricks_ascending(lst[::-1]))
            

print(solve([1, 3, 5, 8]))  # 9
print(solve([3, 10, 9, 9, 4]))  # 15
```

#### Why subtract?

The idea is that `i` represents an ascending series of towers, starting at 0. It so represents an ascending series that has a minimal number of bricks. We need to see at which spot this minimal tower height needs most bricks to get to the *actual* height in the input array at that spot. Here is a visualisation of the first example input, together with that "i" ascending series:

[image]

At the left side we see that the greatest difference between the minimal ascending series and the actual height is at the last spot: 8 - 3 = 5. This 5 is `arr[i] - i`. That is the number of bricks that should be added to each minimal tower. We see the result of this addition in the right-most picture.

Comment: can you please help me understand why are we subtracting and then doing the sum? I am not able to get my head around it

Comment: Added an explanation.